# syncing contents of virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, rsync

I usually sync two computers (mac and linux) using `rsync` so that I can work on either machine. Is it also possible to sync virtual machines (running Windows XP, specifically) on both systems that have been created by VirtualBox? Probably not...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do it with all kinds of routing rules and port forwarding, but what about having each VM use a [shared folder](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) that you are rsyncing?  This way you can rsync through hosts as you normally do and the VMs will pick up and make changes since the folder is shared between host and guest.

Comment: I guess I'd have to sync through the virtual machines...? I do have the shared folder synced already, but there are some configuration files for some software programs that are in their respective program directories I wanted to sync, but looks like it's going to be a real pain...

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting VM on Dropbox as well.. http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=6520